# Add event for contact into Android's contact table

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, contactscontract

**I've worked hard on the following code, but unfortunately, the entry is assigned to the wrong contact. I don't know why. Tested for <strike>hours</strike> days but can't find the mistake. Can you help me?**

I would like to use the code in order to select a person from the contact list (using the contact picker) and then adding an event entry (date of birth) for this person to the contacts table.

**Step 1:**

I've already set the permission in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
```

**Step 2:**

The contact picker's ID is defined:

```
private static final int CONTACT_PICKER_ID = 123;
```

**Step 3:**

The contact picker is called:

```
Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_ID);
```

**Step 4:**

Another method listens for the contact picker's result and tries to add an event for the selected user:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
        switch (requestCode) {  
            case CONTACT_PICKER_ID:
                Uri selectedPerson = data.getData();
                String contactId = selectedPerson.getLastPathSegment();
                // ADD A NEW EVENT FOR THE SELECTED CONTACT --- BEGIN
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                values.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, contactId);
                values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY);
                values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.RAW_CONTACT_ID, contactId);
                values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.LABEL, "");
                values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE, "2010-01-28"); // hard-coded date of birth
                Uri created = null;
                try {
                    created = getContentResolver().insert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                }
                if (created == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Failed inserting the event!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Successfully inserted the event!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                // ADD A NEW EVENT FOR THE SELECTED CONTACT --- END
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The event is successfully inserted to the database and also shown in the Google contacts - but unfortunately it's assigned to the wrong contact. Why is this so? Is my *contactId* wrong that I get from the contact picker?

Comment: I'm not an android expert by any means, but do you need the ability to read the contacts to select one as well as the write capability?

Comment: per http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html the WRITE_CONTACTS doesn't have the ability to read them. again I don't know the answer this is just something that looked off to me.

Comment: Sorry, the permission READ_CONTACTS is set as well. But the reading process is not the problem, anyway. It's the writing which doesn't work.

Comment: Just checking like I said I'm not an android person, but enjoy reading code and that just looked like something that 'might' cause a problem.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the comment! I do appreciate it, really :) I'm glad someone pays attention to this question. And with every try, there's the chance to find the mistake :)

Comment: Did the solution below get you anywhere?

Comment: No, it didn't get me anywhere else, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The activity result that you get back from the contact picker is the full path to the contact. Something like:

```
content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0r7-2C46324E483C324A3A484634/7
```

This is what's in your:

```
Uri selectedPerson = data.getData();
```

This contains both the Contact's LOOKUP_KEY AND the Contact's _ID. However, you need to be using the RawContacts _ID when inserting into the Data table. What you need to do is grab the RawContact's _ID:

```
long rawContactId = -1;
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
      new String[]{RawContacts._ID},
      RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
      new String[]{String.valueOf(contactId)}, null);
try {
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        rawContactId = c.getLong(0);
    }
} finally {
    c.close();
}
```

And then use the `rawContactId`:

```
values.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
```

However, it should be noted that there can be multiple RawContacts per one Contact. You may want to adjust your code so that it adds an event for each RawContact.

Answer (score 1):

One entry is wrong in your content values. The Uri which you get in your onActivityResult data variable is not the raw_contact_id but the contact id. The difference between both is that one contact can contain multiple raw contacts. A raw contact is associated with a single account like Google or Facebook. But a contact can contain multiple raw_contacts.

```
            Uri selectedPerson = data.getData();
            String contactId = selectedPerson.getLastPathSegment();
            // ADD A NEW EVENT FOR THE SELECTED CONTACT --- BEGIN
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            ***values.put(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID, contactId);***
            values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY);
            values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.RAW_CONTACT_ID, contactId);
            values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.LABEL, "");
            values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE, "2010-01-28"); // hard-coded date of birth
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but it doesn't work, actually :( With your code the insert() returns "null" again. So the toast "Failed ..." is shown. When I comment out your new line "values.put(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID, contactId)" then insert() returns a valid URI.

Answer (score 0):

try switching...

```
Uri created = null;
try {
     created = getContentResolver().insert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
}catch (Exception e) {
}
            if (created == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Failed inserting the event!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Successfully inserted the event!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

to...

```
try{
    Uri created = getContentResolver().insert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
    if (created == null) {
         Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Failed inserting the event!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
         Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Successfully inserted the event!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}catch (Exception e) {}
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, this doesn't change anything. Why should it, actually? The exception is thrown in the getContentResolver().insert() line - so it is now still thrown bad "catched"/caught a few steps later. The problem is that insert() throws this exception. Maybe the content that is inserted is wrong (wrong URI, wrong pairs of key-value).

Comment: @MarcoW. I tried to look at that and for whatever reason I saw something that I thought might cause this to change something.  I can't for the life of me remember what it was.  I would have put it in a comment, but SO doesn't have good support for that amount of code in a comment.

Comment: :D It's okay. Thank you again for your will to help :)